# How do I set a toolbar/menu action to use the relevant system default icon in Qt 5?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm using Qt Designer to design a GUI for a PyQt5 app. The app implements a number of actions that are common among most of the apps, namely "New", "Open", "Save", "Save As", "Undo", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste" and "Delete". All the Qt apps I run on my [KDE5] system use the same icons for these so I conclude they are included in the system Qt theme (and the majority if not all of Qt themes probably) and the apps just display the system default icons instead of shipping their own as bundled resources. How do I implement the same in my app design?

Comment: try with: `QIcon.fromTheme("edit-undo")`

Comment: In Qt Designer, enter the name of the relevant icon in the Property Editor under Icon/Theme. This will only work on systems that honour the [freedesktop icon theme spec](https://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) (so probably only X11 platforms). Qt can only ***reliably*** find icons that are installed in the correct places on the target system, and which use the [standard icon naming scheme](https://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html). However, if you're only targeting KDE, you can also use non-standard KDE icon names.